# Why binding 0 port produces "Address already in use"?

Tags: python, sockets, client, port, bind

I have this code:

```
socks = []
for i in range(20):
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.setblocking(False)
   s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
   s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
   socks.append(s)


# ...... Some code triggering s.connect_ex to calculate connection time ......


for s in socks:
  s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
  s.close()
```

Sometimes this code produces the following exception:

```
2022-07-04 16:06:59,147 ERROR - Thread 'Thread-239' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/connection_time/lib/time_socks.py", line 279, in time_socks
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Ps. The code in running as a root user.

Comment: Because you've run out of local ports. Why are you doing this? You don't need to bind a socket before a connect attempt.

Comment: "*You don't need to bind a socket before a connect attempt*" - sometimes you do. It depends on the requirements of the protocol being used, and the setup of the local network. But, even if you don't `bind()` explicitly, `connect()` will to an implicit bind anyway, so if you are running out of local ports then you are just moving the error from one function to another.

Comment: I will suggest that the *reason* for this is that you aren't closing sockets via all execution paths.